# Cannot load modal with different data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui in react and after building the modals it loads only the last element of the object array.

```
<Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Grid container justify="center" spacing={spacing}>
                    {Object.keys(props.listOfAndis).map((keyName, i) => (

                        <Grid item>
                            <Card className={classes.card}>
                                <CardContent>
                                    <Typography>Word of the Day {i}</Typography>
                                    <Typography>be{bull}nev{bull}o{bull}lent</Typography>
                                    <Typography>adjective</Typography>
                                    <Typography>well meaning and kindly.<br/>{'"a benevolent smile"'}</Typography>
                                </CardContent>
                                <CardActions>
                                    <div>
                                        <Button size="small" onClick={handleOpen}>View Profile</Button>
                                    </div>
                                    <Modal
                                        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
                                        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
                                        open={open}
                                        onClose={handleClose}>

                                        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
                                            <IconButton onClick={handleClose} tooltip="Close"
                                                        style={pointer && topRight}> X </IconButton>
                                            <h2 id="simple-modal-title">Current
                                                Project: {props.listOfAndis[keyName].currentProject}</h2>
                                            <p id="simple-modal-description">Name: {props.listOfAndis[keyName].name}</p>
                                            <p id="simple-modal-description">E-mail: {props.listOfAndis[keyName].emailAddress}</p>
                                            <p id="simple-modal-description">Skills: {props.listOfAndis[keyName].skills}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </Modal>
                                </CardActions>
                            </Card>
                        </Grid>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Currently I have 3 mock entries, but only the last one is used for all three modals.
I have tried using key={i} with no success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're controlling all of the modals with a single `open` variable which probably means that all 3 are opening at the same time and the last one is the one on top so it is what you see.

Comment: Similar problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404378/react-antd-showing-multiple-modal-on-array-map/53404616#53404616